# Trying to write a function but int object is not iterable

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a function that accepts a list of integers, a low integer, and a high integer. It then will return the average of the values in the list of integers that lie within the range of the low and high integers.

An example of this might be `get_average_in_range([1, 5, 6, 7, 9], 5, 7)` and the answer returns as 5.5 because only 5 and 6 are within the range of 5 (inclusive) and 7 (exclusive) and 5 and 6 averaged is 5.5

I'm currently getting an error that `'int' object is not iterable`

Here's my code so far:

```
def get_average_in_range(list, low, high):
    min_val = min(low)
    max_val = max(high)
    range = range(min_val, max_val)
    sum_num = 0
    for number in range(range):
        sum_num = sum_num + x
    avg = sum_num / len(list)
    print(avg)
```

Comment: You're overshadowing `range` with an int

Comment: can you share how you call function, we don't have any clue about data types

Comment: @Tuqay Edited the op

Comment: You clobbered the range function with `range = range(min_val, max_val)`. Avoid naming your variables he same as built-in functions and types.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel How might I be able to fix this? Just renaming `range`?

Answer (score 1):

`min` and `max` functions both take an iterable, and you are passing integer to them, that is the reason for the error. Furthermore, you are using keywords for your variables and you will get errors if you don't rename them.

You have too many problems with your algorithm, I will try to fix them, without completely destroying your code.

```
def get_average_in_range(my_list, low, high): # list is keyword, changed it to my_list
    #  min_val = min(low) - no need for these two lines, low and high are already low and high
    #  max_val = max(high)
    my_range = range(min_val, max_val) # range is keyword, so I changed it to my_range

    sum_num = 0
    counter = 0 # for keeping count of numbers in range. 

    for number in my_range: # my_range is a range object, we use it

        count = my_list.count(number)  # getting how many times number is present in my_list
        counter += count  # increasing counter
        sum_num += count # number #inc
    avg = 0.0
    if counter != 0:  # if counter is 0, we keep average as it is
        avg = sum_num / counter # all we need is counter
    print(avg)
```

Actually this is not the best way, this is an awful way. We can optimize it:

```
def get_average_in_range(my_list, low, high):
    sum_num = counter = 0
    for number in my_list:  
        if low <= number < high:
            counter += 1
            sum_num += number 
    avg = 0.0
    if counter != 0:  
        avg = sum_num / counter 
    print(avg)
```

The logic here is checking every number in `my_list` to see if it is in range.

Comment: Ohhh that makes total sense wth. However, I'm not passing a couple testcases now, one where I must pass `(-204, 5)` through the function along with `Returns 0 when given 0`. I'm not really sure how to fix either of these. Have you any idea?

Comment: I missed that point, when there is no number in range, it must return 0

Comment: Hmm. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason of error:**

Min and max functions accept lists as arguments. `low` and `high` are numbers but you treated them like `list` in the following lines:

```py
min_val = min(low)
max_val = max(high)
```

**Do not shadow names:**

```py
# `list` is shadowed here. you cannot use `list` anymore.
def get_average_in_range(list, low, high):
    # ...
    # `range` is shadowed here.
    range = range(min_val, max_val)
    for number in range(range): # you tried to use builtin `range` that assigned line above.
```

**Logical error while calculating average**

You must divide number of items you select, not all.

```py
    avg = sum_num / len(list)
```

**Fixed version:**

```py
def get_average_in_range(numbers, low, high):
    low_index = numbers.index(low) # find index of 'low', for your example: 1
    high_index = numbers.index(high) # find index of 'high', for your example: 3

    range_sum = 0 # set as 0 since we sum
    
    for i in range(low_index, high_index): # iterate between low and high(exclusive)
        range_sum += numbers[i] # add current number
    
    return range_sum / (high_index-low_index) # divide number of items, for your example: 3-1=2

print(get_average_in_range([1, 5, 6, 7, 9], 5, 7))
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! Do you know how I can make it so I can pass negative values through here though? Additionally, I'm not passing a testcase that reads `Returns 0 when given 0`. Do you know why this might be?

Answer (score -1):

This is the pythonic way of doing things:

```
def get_average_in_range(lst, low, high):
    
    filtered_lst = [elem for elem in lst if elem >= low and elem <= high]
    return sum(filtered_lst) / len(filtered_lst)
```

Please don't use the keywords of python like `list` and `range` as variables.